# export entire angular 7 application as a module

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8, angular7-router, micro-frontend

There is a requirement in our project that we have to combine 2 or more sub angular applications into a container angular application through we want to make single page angular portal.

Advantages:

1. we can maintain different code repo's
2. Different teams can work on their own code repo and they can work independently.

so we decided to achieve this with spring Gateway where we want to do following process:

step 1: Create spring gateway application and configured routes

```
        - id: mf-app-one
          uri: http://localhost:4300/
          predicates:
          Path=/appone/**
```

setp 2: To create Main container angular application (running on : 8080 port )
setp 3: to create sub angular application (running on port 8081)

When ever we are hitting the sub application through container application we want to navigate through api gateway which will further hit the configured route and serve the sub application.

--> As of now creating the container application and configure the gateway part is done.
--> Now the question is :

How to export entire sub application as a module so that my container application should think that it is loading a sub module through gateway not a real angular application.

Is there any possibility to do so? That will help us great!

[image]

Comment: Maybe this article will give you a different point of view of achieving the same result --> https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527

Comment: @IvanMihaylov I agree that same result we can achieve but the problem is we need to maintain same code repository for all applications which is not the case in my senario. We want to have different code repositories for each angular application

Comment: Honestly I don't see a problem with that (correct me if Im wrong). In your folder structure you can have multiple git repositories for the separate apps. Something like
`-- Top App
-- .gitIgnore AppA, AppB
-- -- AppA
-- -- .git
-- -- AppB
-- -- .git`

Comment: @IvanMihaylov we can maintain multiple git repositories for each application but when it goes with Jenkins pipe line will it support as i could see the code that when they are included in the container they are mentioned it with relative path like this import {App1SharedModule} 
       from "../../projects/app1/src/app/app.module";
import {App2SharedModule} 
       from "../../projects/app2/src/app/app.module";                                                                      when they are having different repositories how they will fit into Jenkins pipe line

Comment: I am not sure about that since I don't work wit Jenkins but I could image that this should be pretty straight forward as well since most project folders contain more than one project in them in one way or another, but this could be a separate stack overflow question.